# How to alter woocommerce widget filter by attribute widget?

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I use the default Woocommerce widget "Filter by attribute" and I would like to prepend the name of each attributes.
But I don't find any hook on it

Do you know how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

What about extending its class to override the widget?

in your `functions.php`, add this class, you can then change the elements or do conditional statements depending on what you need.

```
/**
 * Layered nav widget
 *
 * @package WooCommerce/Widgets
 * @version 2.6.0
 */

/**
 * Widget layered nav class.
 */
class The_New_Attribute_Widget extends WC_Widget_Layered_Nav {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->widget_cssclass    = 'woocommerce widget_layered_nav woocommerce-widget-layered-nav';
        $this->widget_description = __( 'Display a list of attributes to filter products in your store.', 'woocommerce' );
        $this->widget_id          = 'woocommerce_layered_nav';
        $this->widget_name        = __( 'Filter Products by Attribute', 'woocommerce' );
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular instance of a widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget->update
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New Instance.
     * @param array $old_instance Old Instance.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $this->init_settings();
        return parent::update( $new_instance, $old_instance );
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the settings update form.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget->form
     *
     * @param array $instance Instance.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $this->init_settings();
        parent::form( $instance );
    }

    /**
     * Init settings after post types are registered.
     */
    public function init_settings() {
        $attribute_array      = array();
        $std_attribute        = '';
        $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

        if ( ! empty( $attribute_taxonomies ) ) {
            foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ) {
                if ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name ) ) ) {
                    $attribute_array[ $tax->attribute_name ] = $tax->attribute_name;
                }
            }
            $std_attribute = current( $attribute_array );
        }

        $this->settings = array(
            'title'        => array(
                'type'  => 'text',
                'std'   => __( 'Filter by', 'woocommerce' ),
                'label' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ),
            ),
            'attribute'    => array(
                'type'    => 'select',
                'std'     => $std_attribute,
                'label'   => __( 'Attribute', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => $attribute_array,
            ),
            'display_type' => array(
                'type'    => 'select',
                'std'     => 'list',
                'label'   => __( 'Display type', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'list'     => __( 'List', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'dropdown' => __( 'Dropdown', 'woocommerce' ),
                ),
            ),
            'query_type'   => array(
                'type'    => 'select',
                'std'     => 'and',
                'label'   => __( 'Query type', 'woocommerce' ),
                'options' => array(
                    'and' => __( 'AND', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'or'  => __( 'OR', 'woocommerce' ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get this widgets taxonomy.
     *
     * @param array $instance Array of instance options.
     * @return string
     */
    protected function get_instance_taxonomy( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance['attribute'] ) ) {
            return wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $instance['attribute'] );
        }

        $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

        if ( ! empty( $attribute_taxonomies ) ) {
            foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $tax ) {
                if ( taxonomy_exists( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name ) ) ) {
                    return wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name );
                }
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Get this widgets query type.
     *
     * @param array $instance Array of instance options.
     * @return string
     */
    protected function get_instance_query_type( $instance ) {
        return isset( $instance['query_type'] ) ? $instance['query_type'] : 'and';
    }

    /**
     * Get this widgets display type.
     *
     * @param array $instance Array of instance options.
     * @return string
     */
    protected function get_instance_display_type( $instance ) {
        return isset( $instance['display_type'] ) ? $instance['display_type'] : 'list';
    }

    /**
     * Output widget.
     *
     * @see WP_Widget
     *
     * @param array $args Arguments.
     * @param array $instance Instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! is_shop() && ! is_product_taxonomy() ) {
            return;
        }

        $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();
        $taxonomy           = $this->get_instance_taxonomy( $instance );
        $query_type         = $this->get_instance_query_type( $instance );
        $display_type       = $this->get_instance_display_type( $instance );

        if ( ! taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => '1' ) );

        if ( 0 === count( $terms ) ) {
            return;
        }

        ob_start();

        $this->widget_start( $args, $instance );

        if ( 'dropdown' === $display_type ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'selectWoo' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'select2' );
            $found = $this->layered_nav_dropdown( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type );
        } else {
            $found = $this->layered_nav_list( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type );
        }

        $this->widget_end( $args );

        // Force found when option is selected - do not force found on taxonomy attributes.
        if ( ! is_tax() && is_array( $_chosen_attributes ) && array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $_chosen_attributes ) ) {
            $found = true;
        }

        if ( ! $found ) {
            ob_end_clean();
        } else {
            echo ob_get_clean(); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the currently viewed taxonomy name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function get_current_taxonomy() {
        return is_tax() ? get_queried_object()->taxonomy : '';
    }

    /**
     * Return the currently viewed term ID.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function get_current_term_id() {
        return absint( is_tax() ? get_queried_object()->term_id : 0 );
    }

    /**
     * Return the currently viewed term slug.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function get_current_term_slug() {
        return absint( is_tax() ? get_queried_object()->slug : 0 );
    }

    /**
     * Show dropdown layered nav.
     *
     * @param  array  $terms Terms.
     * @param  string $taxonomy Taxonomy.
     * @param  string $query_type Query Type.
     * @return bool Will nav display?
     */
    protected function layered_nav_dropdown( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type ) {
        global $wp;
        $found = false;

        if ( $taxonomy !== $this->get_current_taxonomy() ) {
            $term_counts          = $this->get_filtered_term_product_counts( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' ), $taxonomy, $query_type );
            $_chosen_attributes   = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();
            $taxonomy_filter_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $taxonomy );
            $taxonomy_label       = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );

            /* translators: %s: taxonomy name */
            $any_label      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_any_label', sprintf( __( 'Any %s', 'woocommerce' ), $taxonomy_label ), $taxonomy_label, $taxonomy );
            $multiple       = 'or' === $query_type;
            $current_values = isset( $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] ) ? $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] : array();

            if ( '' === get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) ) {
                $form_action = remove_query_arg( array( 'page', 'paged' ), add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
            } else {
                $form_action = preg_replace( '%\/page/[0-9]+%', '', home_url( trailingslashit( $wp->request ) ) );
            }

            echo '<form method="get" action="' . esc_url( $form_action ) . '" class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-dropdown">';
            echo '<select class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-dropdown dropdown_layered_nav_' . esc_attr( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . '"' . ( $multiple ? 'multiple="multiple"' : '' ) . '>';
            echo '<option value="">' . esc_html( $any_label ) . '</option>';

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                // If on a term page, skip that term in widget list.
                if ( $term->term_id === $this->get_current_term_id() ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Get count based on current view.
                $option_is_set = in_array( $term->slug, $current_values, true );
                $count         = isset( $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] ) ? $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] : 0;

                // Only show options with count > 0.
                if ( 0 < $count ) {
                    $found = true;
                } elseif ( 0 === $count && ! $option_is_set ) {
                    continue;
                }

                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( urldecode( $term->slug ) ) . '" ' . selected( $option_is_set, true, false ) . '>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</option>';
            }

            echo '</select>';

            if ( $multiple ) {
                echo '<button class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-dropdown__submit" type="submit" value="' . esc_attr__( 'Apply', 'woocommerce' ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Apply', 'woocommerce' ) . '</button>';
            }

            if ( 'or' === $query_type ) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="query_type_' . esc_attr( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . '" value="or" />';
            }

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="filter_' . esc_attr( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( implode( ',', $current_values ) ) . '" />';
            echo wc_query_string_form_fields( null, array( 'filter_' . $taxonomy_filter_name, 'query_type_' . $taxonomy_filter_name ), '', true ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
            echo '</form>';

            wc_enqueue_js(
                "
                // Update value on change.
                jQuery( '.dropdown_layered_nav_" . esc_js( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . "' ).change( function() {
                    var slug = jQuery( this ).val();
                    jQuery( ':input[name=\"filter_" . esc_js( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . "\"]' ).val( slug );

                    // Submit form on change if standard dropdown.
                    if ( ! jQuery( this ).attr( 'multiple' ) ) {
                        jQuery( this ).closest( 'form' ).submit();
                    }
                });

                // Use Select2 enhancement if possible
                if ( jQuery().selectWoo ) {
                    var wc_layered_nav_select = function() {
                        jQuery( '.dropdown_layered_nav_" . esc_js( $taxonomy_filter_name ) . "' ).selectWoo( {
                            placeholder: decodeURIComponent('" . rawurlencode( (string) wp_specialchars_decode( $any_label ) ) . "'),
                            minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
                            width: '100%',
                            allowClear: " . ( $multiple ? 'false' : 'true' ) . ",
                            language: {
                                noResults: function() {
                                    return '" . esc_js( _x( 'No matches found', 'enhanced select', 'woocommerce' ) ) . "';
                                }
                            }
                        } );
                    };
                    wc_layered_nav_select();
                }
            "
            );
        }

        return $found;
    }

    /**
     * Count products within certain terms, taking the main WP query into consideration.
     *
     * This query allows counts to be generated based on the viewed products, not all products.
     *
     * @param  array  $term_ids Term IDs.
     * @param  string $taxonomy Taxonomy.
     * @param  string $query_type Query Type.
     * @return array
     */
    protected function get_filtered_term_product_counts( $term_ids, $taxonomy, $query_type ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $tax_query  = WC_Query::get_main_tax_query();
        $meta_query = WC_Query::get_main_meta_query();

        if ( 'or' === $query_type ) {
            foreach ( $tax_query as $key => $query ) {
                if ( is_array( $query ) && $taxonomy === $query['taxonomy'] ) {
                    unset( $tax_query[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        $meta_query     = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query );
        $tax_query      = new WP_Tax_Query( $tax_query );
        $meta_query_sql = $meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );
        $tax_query_sql  = $tax_query->get_sql( $wpdb->posts, 'ID' );

        // Generate query.
        $query           = array();
        $query['select'] = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT {$wpdb->posts}.ID ) as term_count, terms.term_id as term_count_id";
        $query['from']   = "FROM {$wpdb->posts}";
        $query['join']   = "
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS term_relationships ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = term_relationships.object_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS term_taxonomy USING( term_taxonomy_id )
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS terms USING( term_id )
            " . $tax_query_sql['join'] . $meta_query_sql['join'];

        $query['where'] = "
            WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type IN ( 'product' )
            AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'"
            . $tax_query_sql['where'] . $meta_query_sql['where'] .
            'AND terms.term_id IN (' . implode( ',', array_map( 'absint', $term_ids ) ) . ')';

        $search = WC_Query::get_main_search_query_sql();
        if ( $search ) {
            $query['where'] .= ' AND ' . $search;
        }

        $query['group_by'] = 'GROUP BY terms.term_id';
        $query             = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_filtered_term_product_counts_query', $query );
        $query             = implode( ' ', $query );

        // We have a query - let's see if cached results of this query already exist.
        $query_hash = md5( $query );

        // Maybe store a transient of the count values.
        $cache = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_count_maybe_cache', true );
        if ( true === $cache ) {
            $cached_counts = (array) get_transient( 'wc_layered_nav_counts_' . sanitize_title( $taxonomy ) );
        } else {
            $cached_counts = array();
        }

        if ( ! isset( $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] ) ) {
            $results                      = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
            $counts                       = array_map( 'absint', wp_list_pluck( $results, 'term_count', 'term_count_id' ) );
            $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] = $counts;
            if ( true === $cache ) {
                set_transient( 'wc_layered_nav_counts_' . sanitize_title( $taxonomy ), $cached_counts, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
            }
        }

        return array_map( 'absint', (array) $cached_counts[ $query_hash ] );
    }

    /**
     * Show list based layered nav.
     *
     * @param  array  $terms Terms.
     * @param  string $taxonomy Taxonomy.
     * @param  string $query_type Query Type.
     * @return bool   Will nav display?
     */
    protected function layered_nav_list( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type ) {
        // List display.
        echo '<ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">';

        $term_counts        = $this->get_filtered_term_product_counts( wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' ), $taxonomy, $query_type );
        $_chosen_attributes = WC_Query::get_layered_nav_chosen_attributes();
        $found              = false;
        $base_link          = $this->get_current_page_url();

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $current_values = isset( $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] ) ? $_chosen_attributes[ $taxonomy ]['terms'] : array();
            $option_is_set  = in_array( $term->slug, $current_values, true );
            $count          = isset( $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] ) ? $term_counts[ $term->term_id ] : 0;

            // Skip the term for the current archive.
            if ( $this->get_current_term_id() === $term->term_id ) {
                continue;
            }

            // Only show options with count > 0.
            if ( 0 < $count ) {
                $found = true;
            } elseif ( 0 === $count && ! $option_is_set ) {
                continue;
            }

            $filter_name    = 'filter_' . wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $taxonomy );
            $current_filter = isset( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ? explode( ',', wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_GET[ $filter_name ] ) ) ) : array(); // WPCS: input var ok, CSRF ok.
            $current_filter = array_map( 'sanitize_title', $current_filter );

            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $current_filter, true ) ) {
                $current_filter[] = $term->slug;
            }

            $link = remove_query_arg( $filter_name, $base_link );

            // Add current filters to URL.
            foreach ( $current_filter as $key => $value ) {
                // Exclude query arg for current term archive term.
                if ( $value === $this->get_current_term_slug() ) {
                    unset( $current_filter[ $key ] );
                }

                // Exclude self so filter can be unset on click.
                if ( $option_is_set && $value === $term->slug ) {
                    unset( $current_filter[ $key ] );
                }
            }

            if ( ! empty( $current_filter ) ) {
                asort( $current_filter );
                $link = add_query_arg( $filter_name, implode( ',', $current_filter ), $link );

                // Add Query type Arg to URL.
                if ( 'or' === $query_type && ! ( 1 === count( $current_filter ) && $option_is_set ) ) {
                    $link = add_query_arg( 'query_type_' . wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $taxonomy ), 'or', $link );
                }
                $link = str_replace( '%2C', ',', $link );
            }

            if ( $count > 0 || $option_is_set ) {
                $link      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_link', $link, $term, $taxonomy );
                $term_html = '<a rel="nofollow" href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>';
            } else {
                $link      = false;
                $term_html = '<span>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</span>';
            }

            $term_html .= ' ' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_count', '<span class="count">(' . absint( $count ) . ')</span>', $count, $term );

            echo '<li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term ' . ( $option_is_set ? 'woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item--chosen chosen' : '' ) . '">';
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_term_html', $term_html, $term, $link, $count ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
            echo '</li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';

        return $found;
    }
}
```

then in your `functions.php` again, unregister the default attribute widget and register the new one above:

```
function your_widget_handler() {
      unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Layered_Nav' ); //unregister
      register_widget( 'The_New_Attribute_Widget' ); //Register the new class
} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'your_widget_handler' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the source code and it seems that it's only possible [if you chose "*List*" as the "*Display type*"](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php#L419). If so, then there is a filter applied to the displayed elements:

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_term_html', $term_html, $term, $link, $count );
```

so in order to add custom filter, you can do:

```
function so_62519320_prepend_name( $term_html, $term, $link, $count ) {
    // do stuff
    return $some_modified_value;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_layered_nav_term_html', 'so_62519320_prepend_name', 10, 4 );
```

Unfortunately, [if you chose "*Dropdown*" as the "*Display type*"](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php#L237), then there are no filters applied and it seems that you can't modify labels. There's only

```
esc_html( $term->name )
```

used to display option labels, so the only way to change this is to change the value in the database.